# Asio C++11 Thread Exception: The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced

Tags: multithreading, c++11, boost-asio, mingw-w64

I'm trying to write a HTTPS client connection to iOS and Android using C++11 Asio's header only library (without boost),
and I'm testing the c++ code on Windows 10. (I tested on Windows 8 too, but the problem is the same)

I got an exception, so I write a simple example myself to find out what's happening. This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "asio.hpp"

void hello_world_thread() {
    std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    asio::thread t(
        std::bind(
            &hello_world_thread
        )
    );

    t.join();

    return 0;
}
```

And if I run this inside / outside Code::Blocks I got the following exception:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
>   what():  thread: The attempted operation is not supported for the type
>   of object referenced.
>
> This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an
>   unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more
>   information.

The build command is:

> x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe -std=c++11 -Wall
>   -DASIO_STANDALONE -g -Iasio -c D:\Projektek\C++\AsioTeszt\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
>   x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\AsioTeszt.exe
>   obj\Debug\main.o  -lws2_32 -static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -m64

I had already tried the *-pthread* flag, but the error is the same.

MinGW version: gcc version 5.1.0 (x86_64-win32-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)
Asio version: 1.10.6 (And tried with the Dev release too 1.11.0)

Comment: Does it work if you replace "std::bind(&hello_world_thread)" by "hello_world_thread"? I think the bind is not necessary.

Comment: @PhilippClaßen no, I had tried it before and it gives the same result.
The problem is with the thread's constructor, because if I separate the bind constructor, I can call it before the tread constructor throw an expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I figured out after 3 days of suffering.
The problem was with the MinGW installation, because I selected *win32* at the *Threads* section.
After reinstallation with *posix* threads selected everything works fine.

**Edit**: I again run into this problem but I used the Asio thread in another project. So I started remove everything until I had found out what was missing.

```
#include <map>
```

Without this it won't work.